# Button is not showing in the QtWidget window

Tags: python-2.7, pyside

I have created a gridlayout review GUi window. I added title,author,review labels and LineEdit along with Quit button at the bottom. When i execute the script the quit button is not showing in the output window.

```
     import sys
     from PySide import QtGui,QtCore

     class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

         def __init__(self):
            super(Example, self).__init__()

            self.initUI()

         def initUI(self):

             title = QtGui.QLabel('Title')
             author = QtGui.QLabel('Author')
             review = QtGui.QLabel('Review')

             titleEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
             authorEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
             reviewEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()

             btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit", self)
             btn.resize(50,50)
             btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

             grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
             grid.setSpacing(10)

             grid.addWidget(title, 1, 0)
             grid.addWidget(titleEdit, 1, 1)

             grid.addWidget(author, 2, 0)
             grid.addWidget(authorEdit, 2, 1)

             grid.addWidget(review, 3, 0)
             grid.addWidget(reviewEdit, 3, 1, 5, 1)

             grid.addWidget(btn,6,1)

             self.setLayout(grid) 

             self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
             self.setWindowTitle('Review')    
             self.show()



     def main():

         app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
         ex = Example()
         sys.exit(app.exec_())


     if __name__ == '__main__':
         main()
```

I couldn't find out what is the issue . Where i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `grid.addWidget(btn, 6, 1)` to `grid.addWidget(btn, 8, 1)`. Your `QTextEdit` has height `5` in grid units; therefore `3 + 5 = 8` is first empty spot.

Comment: Thanks @Matphy .Now `grid.addWidget(btn, 8, 1)` is working.